# Error while Insert a row data record into listviewitem

Tags: c#, arrays, listview

```
private void btnDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                
            try
            {
                string[] Row = { "", DocNum.Text, counter00,
                CategoryNo.Text, cmbMeas.Text, cmbSubMeas.Text,
                txtTarget.Text, txtActual.Text, cmbCARNo.Text,
                cmbOverStat.Text, cmbOverStat.Text }

                MMDetailsList.Items.Add(Row); <-- Error
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
```

I've tried this one to put a string record row of data into my listviewitem list without any manipulation on the database.

```
private void btnDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {               
            try
            {
                string[] Row = new string[11]; 
                Row[0] = "";
                Row[1] = DocNum.Text;
                Row[2] = counter00;
                Row[3] = CategoryNo.Text;
                Row[4] = cmbMeas.Text;
                Row[5] = cmbSubMeas.Text;
                Row[6] = txtTarget.Text;
                Row[7] = txtActual.Text;
                Row[8] = cmbCARNo.Text;
                Row[9] = cmbOverStat.Text;
                Row[10] = cmbOverStat.Text;

                MMDetailsList.Items.AddRange(Row); <-- Error
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
```

Sorry about this one how can i add a record into a listview without any manipulation with database record.

Comment: i just want to put the set of row data's into a listview which was input by multiple textbox. the MMDetailsList is the name of my listview it's error is there something i lacked to code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:** You are assigning `String Array` to the `ListView.Items.AddRange()`  function ,
but You need to pass `ListViewItemCollection` to the `ListView.Items.AddRange()` function.

*Note:* You need to use the `AddRange()` function when you want to insert Multiple Rows but here in your case you want to Insert one row at a time, so you don't need to use `AddRange()` function.

**Solution:** you can use `ListView.Items.Add()` function to add one row at a time to the `ListView`.
you need to pass the  `ListViewItem` as argument to the `ListView.Items.Add()` function.
`ListViewItem` takes the `String Array` (in `String Array` each `String` represent one column value, so if you have 10 columns in the `ListView` you should have String Array with `Length` 10) as Argument to add one row into the `ListView`

**Syntax:**

```
ListViewItem listItem=new ListViewItem(String Array);
ListView.Items.Add(listItem);
```

**Sample Code:**

```
ListViewItem listItem=new ListViewItem(ROW);
MMDetailsList.Items.Add(listItem);
```

**Complete Code:**

```
private void btnDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {               
            try
            {
                string[] Row = new string[11]; 
                Row[0] = "";
                Row[1] = DocNum.Text;
                Row[2] = counter00;
                Row[3] = CategoryNo.Text;
                Row[4] = cmbMeas.Text;
                Row[5] = cmbSubMeas.Text;
                Row[6] = txtTarget.Text;
                Row[7] = txtActual.Text;
                Row[8] = cmbCARNo.Text;
                Row[9] = cmbOverStat.Text;
                Row[10] = cmbOverStat.Text;

                ListViewItem listItem=new ListViewItem(ROW);
                MMDetailsList.Items.Add(listItem);

            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
```

Comment: You are Welcome :) I'm Glad tobe help of you.